# Migrating to xcframwork Xcode 12.5, dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage, xcframework, xcode12.5

#### Environment

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- Big sur 11.3.1
- Xcode 12.5
- Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)
- Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0

#### Problem

Up until Xcode 12.4, we used [this workaround](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md) to get frameworks for our project and the those frameworks are in the form of bundles (yellow briefcase icons). Also, I need to hand carve a `Carthage Copy File` script (under Build Phase) for each of my targets, which is annoying and error prone.

A few days ago I read the Carthage official doc and it suggests to use `xcframework`. From the steps it sounds like the annoying `copy file` step is no longer needed and I decided to give it shot.

I followed the [migration steps](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#migrating-a-project-from-framework-bundles-to-xcframeworks) exactly. I also changed the framework search path to make it point from `$(PROJECT_DIR)/YOUR_PROJECT/Carthage/Build/iOS` to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/YOUR_PROJECT/Carthage/Build` . The app just ran in the simulator but it was too early to cheer up and it crashes whenever I tried to run it in an iPhone. In the debugger console it complains

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Auth0.framework/Auth0
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9575D8AA-BD35-447B-ACC3-F8545CDB62EE/FIT dev.app/FIT dev
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

#### Solution

Finally I came across this [Medium post](https://kevinle.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-on-using-carthage-dependency-manager-a29c15f9a1ac) from 2 years ago, where it suggests to `embed & sign` the frameworks that were dragged and dropped to the project.  I did same thing to my project by changing the `Embed` status of some of the frameworks from `Do not embed` to `Embed & Sign` (from the tab `General/Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`).

Bingo! The project runs in both simulator and real device, the UI test also runs as before.

The [migration steps](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#migrating-a-project-from-framework-bundles-to-xcframeworks) in Carthage's official doc didn't mention this step at all. Also, I couldn't find any posts that addresses the similar issue. So I just want to share my migration steps and hope this may be helpful some else

- Follow [migration steps](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#migrating-a-project-from-framework-bundles-to-xcframeworks) exactly (If you have multiple targets, the trick here is to drop all the xcframeworks under the `/Frameworks` group in your file navigator, in this way you can link the xcframeworks to all your targets in one shot)

[image]

[image]

- Set the `embed` status for your newly added xcframeworks, see the snapshots below, where I put the frameworks into three groups

  - Green, third party library, e.g. auth0, alamofire -> `Embed and Sign`
  - Orange -> Development library -> `Embed and Sign`
  - The rest, in my case are xcframeworks for Firebase -> `Do not embed`

[image: Set embed status]

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered my question in itself, please see the question, thanks :)